# How to make multiple v-progress-linear with v-for,

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I want to create multiple Progress linear with v-for. I cannot use v-progress-linear with v-for. I can't address the object properly. "NaN%" is displayed instead of the percentage.

```
<div class="course__card" v-for="(myCourse, m) in myCourses" :key="m">

...

  <v-progress-linear
     class="rounded-xl"
    :v-model="myCourse.subject"
    height="35"
    width="200"
    background="#F2F2F2"
    color="#83D2B7"
  >
    <strong>{{ Math.ceil(myCourse.subject) }}%</strong>
  </v-progress-linear>

...

</div>

export default {
  data: () => ({
    art: 46,
    maths: 11,
    rating: 4.5,
    myCourses: [
      { img: require('@/assets/course-art-mini.png'), name: 'Rassomchilik', subject: 'art'},
      { img: require('@/assets/course-maths-mini.png'), name: 'Matematikadan oliy ta’lim muassalari uchun tayyorgarlik kursi', subject: 'maths' }
    ],
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Math.ceil converts any number in string format to nearest upper integer value. Eg: `Math.ceil('123.01') = 124`, but in case the value that you are passing is not a valid number `Math.ceil('art') = NaN`. NaN is `Not a Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Math.ceil()` on `myCourse.subject` which appears to be a string (and not a number, hence `NaN%`) in your data.

Otherwise, this looks good and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Billal Begueradj thanks for your replay. I understand. I changed my code and everything worked out.

```
<v-progress-linear
  class="rounded-xl"
  :v-model="myCourse.subject"
  height="35"
  width="200"
  background="#F2F2F2"
  color="#83D2B7"
  >
  <template v-slot="{ value }">
    <strong>{{ Math.ceil(value) }}%</strong>
  </template>
</v-progress-linear>
```

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    myCourses: [
      {
        img: require("@/assets/course-art-mini.png"),
        name: "Rassomchilik",
        subject: "46",
      },
      {
        img: require("@/assets/course-maths-mini.png"),
        name: "Matematikadan oliy ta’lim muassalari uchun tayyorgarlik kursi",
        subject: "11",
      },
    ],
  })
}
```